# I need to create a vector containing image objects on R

Tags: r, image

I need to create a vector containing image objects on R, and then to program a loop in which I take and display those images.

The following is an example of what I want to do, in case I could not make myself clear:

```
    for (i in 1:6){
      for (j in (i+1):7) {
              display(combine(as.Image(image[i]),as.Image(image[j])),method="raster",all=TRUE)
}
```

There I am using EBImage. The problem is that this package is not suitable to my ends.

The question is: Do you know another package that allows to display images AND to do it in the way I need?

Comment: This is really unclear. But, try using the raster package instead. Depending on your format just call raster() with your file name, or brick()  - to get all layers, or stack() - to get all layers from multiple files.